# how to find files containing a string using egrep

Tags: linux, find, grep

I would like to find the files containing specific string under linux.
I tried something like but could not succeed:

find . -name *.txt | egrep mystring

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here you are sending the file names (output of the `find command`) as input to egrep; you actually want to run egrep on the contents of the files.

Here are a couple of alternatives:

```
find . -name "*.txt" -exec egrep mystring {} \;
```

or even better

```
find . -name "*.txt" -print0 | xargs -0 egrep mystring
```

Check the [find command help](http://linux.about.com/od/commands/l/blcmdl1_find.htm) to check what the single arguments do.
The first approach will spawn a new process for every file, while the second will pass more than one file as argument to egrep; the -print0 and -0 flags are needed to deal with potentially nasty file names (allowing to separate file names correctly even if a file name contains a space, for example).

Comment: You are missing `\+` or `\;` at the end of your first command.

Comment: Does't this attempt to find the filename within mystring? I think he's looking for the other way around.

Comment: @spatz: handy feature about \+ is that + is not a special character to most shells (I don't know of any shells where it is special, but am reluctant to say all), so you don't need the backslash.

Answer (score 3):

try:

```
find . -name '*.txt' | xargs egrep mystring
```

There are two problems with your version:

**Firstly**, `*.txt` will first be expanded by the shell, giving you a listing of files in the current directory which end in `.txt`, so for instance, if you have the following:

```
[dsm@localhost:~]$ ls *.txt
test.txt
[dsm@localhost:~]$
```

your `find` command will turn into `find . -name test.txt`. Just try the following to illustrate:

```
[dsm@localhost:~]$ echo find . -name *.txt
find . -name test.txt
[dsm@localhost:~]$
```

**Secondly**, `egrep` does not take filenames from `STDIN`. To convert them to arguments you need to use `xargs`

Comment: I would also suggest enclosing the pattern following -name in quotes to prevent the shell from doing pattern matching on it

Comment: I would like to thank all of you providing such comprehensive answers.

Answer (score 1):

```
find . -name *.txt | egrep mystring
```

That will not work as `egrep` will be searching for `mystring` within the output generated by `find . -name *.txt` which are just the path to `*.txt` files.

Instead, you can use `xargs`:

```
find . -name *.txt | xargs egrep mystring
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use

```
find . -iname *.txt -exec egrep mystring \{\} \;
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example that will return the file paths of a all `*.log` files that have a line that begins with `ERROR`:

```
find . -name "*.log" -exec egrep -l '^ERROR' {} \;
```

Answer (score 1):

there's a recursive option from egrep you can use

```
egrep -R "pattern" *.log
```

Comment: This does not work. The -R option only recurses into directories if they are supplied in the argument list. In which case all files in those directories will be read not only files ending in .log. If you have any success with this method it is because there are files ending in .log in the current directory because then the shell parses the *.log.

Comment: Maybe with `egrep -R "pattern" --include=*.log .`?

Answer (score 1):

If you only want the filenames:

```
find . -type f -name '*.txt' -exec egrep -l pattern {} \;
```

If you want filenames and matches:

```
find . -type f -name '*.txt' -exec egrep pattern {} /dev/null \;
```